# Why this html and javascript code do not work?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

Requirement is to:

Write code for a JavaScript function that:

- takes two integers as parameters
- sums all the numbers from the lowest of the parameters to the highest of the parameters. For example, if the parameters were 2 and 4 the result would be 9, that is 2+3+4=9
- the function should then return the value of the result

This is my code, I couldn't find the error.

```
<html>
   <head>
   <title>function</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function sum(a,b) {
       var c=min(a,b);
       for (c;c<b;c++) {
           var d=c+(c+1);
           return d;
       }
       document.getElementById("para").innerHTML=sum();
   }

</script>

</head>

<body>

<form onsubmit="sum()">

<p>Number 01</p><input type="text" name="t1">

<p>Number 02</p><input type="text" name="t2">

<input type="submit" value="sb">

</form>

<p id="para"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your problem with this code?

Comment: You're calling `sum()` but you aren't supplying any parameters, you're returning from your function for each iteration of your for loop, and you are setting the innerHTML property value as the same function which probably isn't functional. If you create a JSFiddle and explain what you're trying to accomplish and why you think what you wrote should work, we can probably help more.

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy It does not show the result

Comment: @Goose I parse t1 and t2 values on submit, right?

Comment: @Maduranga did my approach work out for you?

Comment: @Han Arantes yes, it's working. Thanks! and can't I directly pass parameters using form onclick event like I tried in my code?

Comment: @Maduranga so.. can you check my answer as correct :)? you can pass parameters using angular-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code has a couple of mistakes:

1. You are not passing any parameter to the sum function!
2. min() doesn't exists in your code!
3. you need to assign an id to your inputs!

This approach works for what you need:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <title>function</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function sum() {
       var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("t1").value);
       var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("t2").value);
       var vmin = Math.min(a,b);
       var vmax = Math.max(a,b);
       var d = 0;
       for (vmin;vmin<=vmax;vmin++) {
           d+=vmin;
       }
       document.getElementById("para").innerHTML=d;
   }

</script>

</head>

<body>

<form>

    <p>Number 01</p><input type="text" name="t1" id="t1">

    <p>Number 02</p><input type="text" name="t2" id="t2">

    <input type="button" value="sb" onclick="sum()">

</form>

<p id="para"></p>

</body>
</html>
```